# PHP : Display a message using a function without using echo

Tags: php, function, echo

Here's a simple php function.

```
function hello($name) {
  $message = 'Hello '.$name.' How are you feeling today?';
  return $message;
}
```

And as you know, when I execute this function it returns a message.

```
<?php
  echo hello(Stackoverflow);
?>
```

Output :

```
Hello Stackoverflow How are you feeling today?
```

Is there any way to display this message without using the echo (at least not here)

like `<?php hello(Stackoverflow); ?>` and it should return the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's the case, your function should have `echo`.

```
function hello($name) {
  $message = 'Hello '.$name.' How are you feeling today?';
  echo $message;
}
```

Comment: Roccos, you should change the title. This answer does not match the title.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, he only meant not using `echo` as `echo hello(Stackoverflow);`. Take note of *(atleast not here)* in his question.

Comment: The thing is, once you put the `echo` into the function, you can only unit-test it by buffering the output, which is unwanted. Using `echo` on the return value of `hello()` is the clean way to approach this. In other words, the OP's `hello` function is fine the way it is. On a sidenote, if you put echo into the function like this, there is no need to use a temporary and you also don't need to concat the string before outputting. Just pass the arguments to echo, e.g. `echo 'Hello ', $name, '…'`

Comment: Also, the OP asked that the function should **return** the message. S/he's probably confusing *returning* and *displaying*, but strictly speaking when exchanging the `return` for an `echo` or `printf`, `hello` no longer *returns* the `$message`, but `NULL`

Comment: @Ruel, I was talking about the title, not the question itself. The first time I saw the question (title), I thought the OP meant 'not using echo at all'.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to display something. [`printf`](http://php.net/printf) is very useful in this case.

```
<?php
function hello($name){
   printf('Hello %s How are you feeling today?', $name);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey this worked as well, But i prefer to use echo instead of print. I didn't wanted to use echo while executing the function. Thats All.

Comment: same problem as for putting `echo` into the function in terms of unit-testing. It's better to use `return sprintf(…` and echo outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

If short tags is on `<?= hello('Stackoverflow') ?>` should work. But it's not recomended to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function hello($name) {
  $message = 'Hello '.$name.' How are you feeling today?';
  echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always print it to the PHP error log: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= hello('String') ?>
```